# GC Custom Action on Add/Edit Form

Tags: grocery-crud

Good day.Essentially, I am trying to have a custom action button on the add/update form. Is there a way to create a callback that gets fired only when I click the "save" button as distinct from "save and go back to list" button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of built-in way to do it, but you can do following (quick and dirty) thing in order to differ weather "Save" or "Save and go back to list" was clicked:

Following steps are used for flexgrid theme and ADD action. You should adjust the code by the theme you are using and also add same code for EDIT action.

First, add one hidden field into file:

/assets/grocery_crud/themes/flexgrid/views/add.php

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_button_name" id="my_button_name" value="save" />
```

just above comment line:

```
<!-- End of hidden inputs -->
```

Second, go to /assets/grocery_crud/themes/flexigrid/js/flexgrid-add.js

and add following line:

```
$('#my_button_name').val("save_and_close");
```

just below line:

```
save_and_close = true;
```

We will update this hidden field only if "Save and go back" was clicked, else we will keep default "Save" value.

Third, go to your controller, and read this field from POST array:

```
if (isset($_POST["my_button_name"]) && $_POST["my_button_name"] == 'save_and_close' )
{
    // save and close clicked
}
else
{
    // save clicked
}
```

That should be all. If you figure out "more proper" way to do it, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for answering Ivan. However, this affects all add/edit forms and not just where I want it.  . But I think I can use this idea.

Answer (score 0):

open `\assets\grocery_crud\themes\datatables\edit.php`

then paste before:

```
<div class='form-content form-div'>
    <?php echo form_open( $update_url, 'method="post" id="crudForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"'); ?>"
```

PASTE THIS

```
<?php switch ($this->basic_db_table) {
                case "table1":
                    ?><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
                        button text 1
                    </button><?php
                    break;
                case "table2":
                    ?><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
                        text table2
                    </button><?php
                    ?><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
                        text table 3 showed
                    </button><?php
                    break;
                default:
                    echo "No buttons";
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - you can also add code as well as the comments in the code itself 
- in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question. This is especially important for an older question and the questions that already have answers.